# Dojo Twitter Bootstrap and Dijits

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dojo

I am new to Dojo and Dijit Themes and I found a Dijit Theme with bootstrap styling, here: http://thesociable.github.com/dbootstrap/.

I only need the use the theme with Dojo dijits and I really don´t know anything about the Dojo build system. My purpose is to integrate dijits with an already existing site.

How do I use the dijit theme? Does anyone know about any site that has a ready to use version, easy to integrate with Dojo Bootstrap.

I think I never saw something to hard to integrate.

Answer (score 5):

I could not find anyone using this or any pre-built version of it.  Also, I could not get the build.py script to work (perhaps a Windows issue).  However I managed to compile the [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) theme files using Node.

I've made a [fork of the dbootstrap](https://bitbucket.org/ssimpo/dbootstrap/overview) project (**NB:** I do do not intend working on this fork, it's just for the purposes of this question.  Although, a Dojo bootstrap theme is a nice concept, so might use it at some point).

I've made a [zip of the compiled theme](https://bitbucket.org/ssimpo/dbootstrap/downloads) this includes an example page *test.html*, which shows how to use it.  You could just use a standard <link /> tag that links directly to the compiled css:

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="scripts/bootstrap/theme/dbootstrap/dbootstrap.css"
/>
```

You could then style the page in the usual dojo manor:

```
<body class="dbootstrap">
```

However, the author includes some extra features that need to be imported using Javascript.  I suggest you include the theme using a require (as shown in the example file and below):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "bootstrap",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready"
    ], function(dbootstrap, parser, ready){
        ready(function(){
            parser.parse();
    })
});
</script>
```

This ensures that bootstrap is loaded before the page is parsed for Dojo widgets.  You also need to turn off automatic parsing of widgets on the page and set the location for the bootstrap module (and xstyle, used by dbootstrap) in dojoConfig, eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        "async": true,
        "parseOnLoad": false,
        "packages": [{
            "name": "bootstrap",
            "location":"/scripts/bootstrap",
            "main":"main"
        }, {
            "name": "xstyle",
            "location":"/scripts/xstyle"
        }]
    };
</script>
```

You'll also need to include the class attribute on **<body>** described above.

It's all a bit convoluted but the example file should make it a bit clearer.  It should also, be noted that loading css in this manor is not really good practice, it will most probably lead to a delay in styling page widgets.

**NB:**  There is a [Dojo Bootstrap module](http://dojobootstrap.com/) that might interest you, if you are trying to achieve bootstrap style components in Dojo.

Comment: Thanks guys i will SURELLY lookt into it

Comment: Stephen, i am going to try the same thing with the dojo Bootstrap module since the thesociable is not ready for IE. Now i have the same problemto to put it to work on my local machine. Have you tried it already?

Answer (score 5):

I have uploaded a pre-built version of the theme to http://thesociable.github.com/dbootstrap/download/dbootstrap.tar.gz and am working on the Windows build issue reported at https://github.com/thesociable/dbootstrap/issues/29

In the meantime Stephen Simpson's answer and the project [README](https://github.com/thesociable/dbootstrap) will hopefully get you there. If you have any other issues then feel free to report them at https://github.com/thesociable/dbootstrap/issues

Comment: Thanks guys i will SURELLY lookt into it

Comment: The pre built version worked perfectly thanks, great work
Now the issue with windows is not closed. wright?
I´ll be watching the project on git

Comment: Hi there

I finnaly was able to use the pre-built version of of the dbootstrap theme(https://github.com/thesociable/dbootstrap/). And it works well.
The thing is am not sure on how to "inverse" the menu, so i just added a class "inverse" on the dijit/MenuBar.
Now the menu bar is "inversed" in firefox but not on IE(IE8 and IE9).
Is there any workaround this while a windows build is not possible?
I have opened an issue on this on the project's GitHub.

Thanks

Comment: After more testes i saw that dbootstrap is broken for IE. It´s not only the menu, the sliders are broken too for IE8. I know that the author only testedit on Firefox.....I am going to try the Dojo Bootstrap module

Comment: What areas is it broken for on IE? I'm currently using this on a project but since I use Linux I've not tested it on IE yet.  I'm using buttons, alerts and dialogs with a few standard widgets like textbox, checkbox, radio ...etc.